# Examples of VS2015 + Cordova + Angular2

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, angular

I'm trying to find a quick start tutorial for a `Visual Studio 2015` `Apache Cordova` Project using `Angular 2` + `TypeScript`.

The latest examples are already out of date or don't apply to Cordova.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ngconf2015demo
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/03/12/a-preview-of-angular-2-and-typescript-in-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: We don't yet have an Angular2 + Typescript Cordova sample.  You can file a request for one on the [http://github.com/microsoft/cordova-samples](http://github.com/microsoft/cordova-samples) site, under “Issues.”

Answer (score 3):

This sample app was recently posted to GitHub.

https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS-Angular2-beta

I know it was written by the author of this question, but if anyone comes here later you should check out what Dean assembled.

Comment: Jordan,  Thanks for adding the link.  If anyone has the chance to check out the repo and encounters problems, needs clarification, has a question or suggestion, ... Please add an issue on the repo.  

Thanks,